# Merge column headers in table typeset using pgfplotstables

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I have a table where the columns are narrow, except for the column headers. I am typesetting the table using pgfplots, and I need a way to specify that certain header columns should be merged.

MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} 

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


% set column separator for our csv loading package
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\scriptsize
\caption{caption}
\label{tab:hierarchical_vs_soa}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    begin table=\begin{tabular},
    header=true,
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    every first row/.style={after row=\midrule},
    string type,
    columns/1/.style={column name=},
    columns/3/.style={column name=},
    columns/4/.style={column name=},
    columns/6/.style={column name=},
    columns/7/.style={column name=},
    columns/9/.style={column name=},
    end table=\end{tabular}
    ]{data.csv}
\end{table*}


\end{document}
```

with a sample CSV file

```
header,,WIDETEXT,,,WIDETEXT MORE,,,WIDESTTEXTHERE, 
,A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C
A,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1
B,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1
C,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1
```

How can I achieve this simply?

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it automatically, but it's possible to declare a `\multicolumn` header within `before row` option.

As you can see, first row (widetext header) has been commented and second row acts a header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every head row/.style={
        before row={%
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Widetext} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Widetext more} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Widetext here}\\
        },
        after row=\midrule,
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule},
    columns/0/.style ={column name={}},
    col sep=comma, row sep=\\,
    string type,
]{
%header,,WIDETEXT,,,WIDETEXT MORE,,,WIDESTTEXTHERE,\\ 
,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I\\
A,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1\\
B,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1\\
C,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1\\
}
\caption{A very nice table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not ideal but it works.

Comment: Actually I just noticed this approach as a problem because the next row are A B C A B C but you changed the CSV data to have unique names instead - the table renders as " A B C A-index4 B-index5 ... "

Comment: @user1207217 Yes, I changed because I didn't know how to solve it. I supose `pgfplots` doesn't like different columns with similar name and adds `-index #` to distinguish. Probably this behavior can be changed, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with this solution (given by @Ignasi):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} 

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every head row/.style={
        before row={%
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Widetext} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Widetext more} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Widetext here}\\
        },
        after row=\midrule,
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule},
    columns/0/.style ={column name={}},
    col sep=comma, row sep=\\,
    string type,
]{
%header,,WIDETEXT,,,WIDETEXT MORE,,,WIDESTTEXTHERE,\\ 
,A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C\\
A,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1\\
B,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1\\
C,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1\\
}
\caption{A very nice table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Where the "header" rows were getting "-index*" appended in order to be unique. I worked around it like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} 

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A very nice table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    header=false,
    every head row/.style={after row={\toprule header & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Widetext} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Widetext more} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Widetext here}\\ \midrule}},
    every first row/.style={after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    string type,
    columns/0/.style={column name=},
    columns/1/.style={column name=},
    columns/2/.style={column name=},
    columns/3/.style={column name=},
    columns/4/.style={column name=},
    columns/5/.style={column name=},
    columns/6/.style={column name=},
    columns/7/.style={column name=},
    columns/8/.style={column name=},
    columns/9/.style={column name=},
    col sep=comma, row sep=\\,
    string type,
]{
%header,,WIDETEXT,,,WIDETEXT MORE,,,WIDESTTEXTHERE,\\ 
,A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C\\
A,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1\\
B,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1\\
C,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1\\
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But I dislike the solution because extra space is left at the top of the table due to invisible blank headers, and having to specify each column name.

Comment: Just a suggestion, I think you should write a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) instead of answering yourself. There will be more opportunities to find someone who reads (and perhaps answer) it.